# SAS connection with PHP

Tags: php, sas, analytics

Basically I have my SAS installed in a server and now I am developing a dashboard in local system and its server side scripting is done in php. Is there any way I can access the SAS server and run Proc through local

Answer (score 0):

Follow Below steps.[source](https://communities.sas.com/t5/ODS-and-Base-Reporting/Connection-to-SAS-Dataset-thru-PHP-application/td-p/119242)

> 1. install sas odbc drivers
> 2. change your PHP.INI, include "php_pdo_odbc.dll";
> 3. access your SAS database through PHP PDO ODBC

Comment: Thanks for the answer but didnt work for me. Tried this already

Answer (score 0):

Yes - subject to any issues with CORS (if your page is not being served by the SAS mid tier), you can run metadata-registered SAS code by calling a Stored Process object.

I've written a summary of this approach [here](http://rawsas.blogspot.co.uk/2015/12/building-web-apps-with-sas.html), with a very detailed explanation [here](https://github.com/rawsas/apps/blob/master/sgf2017.pdf). In short, you can utilise an open source data adapter which makes it very easy to connect to the SAS server and run your "Proc" accordingly.

A guide is also available [here](http://rawsas.blogspot.co.uk/2016/10/building-sas-apps-locally-with-visual.html) for connecting to SAS when running your dashboard locally - basically you need to configure the adapter sot it knows your hosturl, and set your browser to ignore the same origin policy.